# How to access datagrid in View from ViewModel in Silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, mvvm

Hai i'm doing one silverlight app that uses MVVM architecture.
  The Scenario is this. I have one combobox and datagrid in same page.
 I have use ObservableCollection to bind the values in Datagrid and in that collection i have three fields namely Fname,Sname and Dept.
 I bind Dept in Combobox but if i select any one of department means that value does not update in DataGrid. ie., i have created the code in ViewModel and i use LINQ query and i have Fetched the value also in,

var semp = from s in Employees where s.Dept.Equals(Names.Dept) select s;

i need to send this semp datasource to Datagrid in View.
Datagrid Syntax is :

```
<my:DataGrid x:Name="McDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="130,151,0,0" Height="137" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowBackground="#AA5D9324" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="196">
        </my:DataGrid>
```

Help me if u Know...

Comment: Have you implemented inotifypropertychanged in your view model?

Comment: Yes i implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModel..

Comment: I hope you call the OnPropertyChanged() event in your Employees property? I define my ItemsSource like this and it worked for me ItemsSource="{Binding AllBuyers}"

Comment: its okay muhammad Kashif.. But here my question is i have already fetched the data in linq query. but this query is located in ViewModel. i need to pass this data to DataGrid in View.. Is it posible

Comment: Store your query result in Employees . it should change the Grid . because this is the ItemShource property for Grid. Try and tell if it helps.

Comment: Then you should show your code. specially ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ViewModel Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Silverlight_MVVM.Model;
using Silverlight_MVVM.Utils;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Silverlight_MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class EmployeeListViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

        public EmployeeListViewModel()
        {
            Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData ();

        }
        private string _fname;
        public string Fname
        {
            get
            {
                return _fname;
            }
            set
            {
                _fname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Fname");
            }
        }
        private string _sname;
        public string Sname
        {
            get
            {
                return _sname;
            }
            set
            {
                _sname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Sname");
            }
        }
        private string _dept;
        public string Dept
        {
            get
            {
                return _dept;
            }
            set
            {
                _dept = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Dept");
            }
        } 
        private Employee _SelectedEmployee;
        public Employee  SelectedEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedEmployee;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedEmployee = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            }
        }
        private string _demp;
        public string demp
        {
            get
            {
                return _demp;
            }
            set
            {
                _demp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("demp");
            }
        }

        private Employee _Names;
        public Employee Names
        {
            get
            {
                return _Names;
            }
            set
            {
                _Names = value;

                List<Employee> myList = new List<Employee>();
                IEnumerable<Employee> myEnumerable = myList;
              //  List<Employee> listAgain = myEnumerable.ToList();
               // Employees = (ObservableCollection<Employee>)Employees.Where(_ => _.Dept.Equals(Names.Dept));
                RaisePropertyChanged("Names");
            }
        }

        public void HandleShowMessage()
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Hello " + Names + ",Welcome to EventTrigger for MVVM.");

        }
        public RelayCommand _AddEmployeeCommand;
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a command that show the customer.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand AddEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AddEmployeeCommand == null)
                {
                    _AddEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => this.AddEmployee(),
                        param => this.CanAddEmployee
                        );
                }
                return _AddEmployeeCommand;
            }
        }

        public bool CanAddEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                 return true;
            }
        }


        public void AddEmployee()
        {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
            if (Names == null)
            {
                newEmployee.Fname = this.Fname;
                newEmployee.Sname = this.Sname;
                newEmployee.Dept = this.Dept;
                Employees.Add(newEmployee);
                //SelectedEmployee = newEmployee.ToString();
            }
            else //This is the event for getting selected item through combobox and the linq query fetching
            {
             Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData();

             var semp = from emp in Employees where emp.Dept.Equals(Names.Dept) select emp;



            }
        }



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        // [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion


    }
}
```